# cryptojs can not decrypt multiline

Tags: javascript, cryptography

this code is works fine:

```
example()
{

    const str = `U2FsdGVkX1/qtIGwjiv+C8ZTZi6ON8ajE/4GlqQKIIE=`;
    const info2 = crypto.AES.decrypt(str, 'secret').toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);
    console.log({ info2 });
}
```

but this code return error "Malformed UTF-8 data"

```
        example()
        {

            const str = `U2FsdGVkX1+/lQKCg5MvWj/PhcqQrK3ao2/knwKQ+Ekdn/vXmDuPBCNaxSxa3/6A
e1BWw4u4+72bNUExwPmzFg1+AZ1VkYL901YwIyy/Mpk+kNxaeJd+ukerJpSF7Tk1
n+BljkOtoMCVUkM+QLHPTlnvwvcFVqPK0+gr47zl7aFGt4wXRQRdNmgN+4GJuvY2
oHRxdwwk/LY4Kkjy6D1OI31eB5szbAisCJPq1qswmxqqpchq8GyNSSn3YbLx1OQ3`;
            const info2 = crypto.AES.decrypt(str, 'secret').toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);
            console.log({ info2 });
        }
```

rawdata(decrypted text) is :

```
arashisonluPlease enter the full name of your app. You can change this at any time. To bypassthis prompt next time, supply name, the first argument to ionic start.
```

Comment: please help it is an emergency project

Comment: Please provide additional information. Obviously, running the code in `example` will not result in  output from the ionic cli since they are unrelated.